# Woocommerce product layout issue when customising width

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the Wordpress plugin "Woocommerce".

I wasn't happy with the way that the standard four column layout of my products meant that they all became too small when the browser width became narrower, so I've tried to use media queries to turn them into a three column layout when the browser reaches -1250px.

There were a few issues with the margin css that the plugin uses, in the sense that it is preset to have a margin-right on all but the last product.
I've changed this to target the third item instead of the fourth by using

`.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(3n+3) { 
    margin-right: 0px; 
}`

I then fixed the fourth by adding the right margin, giving it the default margin value of `margin: 0 3.8% 2.992em 0;` initially set by the plugin.

But for some reason the items after the third one are floating all over the place and I'm not sure why.

Can any body tell me what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

An example page that shows this problem is: http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/product-category/prints/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me. If you look at the css, woocommerce assigns a class of 'last' to the last item (or, `li`) in a row, and 'first' to the first item.

When you resize the window and change to a 3-item structure, what was the last item becomes the first.

You need to target those classes, maybe removing their properties at specific breakpoints, or altogether. You can start by trying to remove `clear` properties for .first and .last.

Comment: Hmm, you're right about the clear properties. However, I knew about `.last` but I can't seem to find `.first`. Maybe they changed this in an update. Anyway I added `clear: none` to the standard product selector and this seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: When you resize to a 3 column layout your 5th list item has a class of first. Glad you sorted it anyway :)